# promises implementation used in Ember framework

Tags: javascript, ember.js, promise

The question is: is Ember using RSVP library for promises implementation as *hard dependency*? I mean: can't ember go without rsvp.js? I've seen [the docs](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/RSVP.Promise.html) but I didn't find any information, whether I can use some other promises implemenation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Ember has a hard dependency on RSVP - unless you're willing to shim it by writing an adapter from another library you'll have to use it.

On the bright side RSVP is a relatively fast and modern promise implementation with unhandled rejection tracking and pretty strong tooling.

Comment: "with unhandled rejection tracking" - this doesn't seem like a bright side, does it? :) I mean, it's hard to debug if there's no error trace...

Comment: @tkoomzaaskz this is an extremely bright side - it means that you can add a RSVP.oמ("error" handler and get unhandled rejections logged. For example if you have a typo in your code in a then handler - in some promise libraries like Q it will be a silent error but RSVP will let you log it.

Comment: So in Ember you'd get a console error in case you typo an error handler? And in Q, for example, there are built-in handlers that will make errors silent?

Comment: @tkoomzaaskz in Bluebird all errors are verbose by default. In RSVP errors are silent by default but you can add a handler to log them. In Q all errors are silent by default and there is nothing you can do about it.